# Exoplayer show empty white screen when try to run live video on real device

Tags: android, exoplayer, android-tv, exoplayer2.x

I am facing a real problem, after I finish the development of TV android app and test it on emulator, when install the app on real device, all video files is working but all live video show white screen and none of the video or the audio running

I am using the same code in the demo that provide in github

this is the link of the code : https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/demos/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/demo

can you please advice as soon as you can ?

Comment: Do you get any errors in Logcat?

Comment: it is working in emulator with no error, how can I get logcat from TV device ?

Comment: Depending on the android tv you are using there are steps to enable debugging. Generally they all support Connecting ADB over wifi - https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless

Comment: the problem that I do not have TV device, I write code and test it on emulator and send it to the client to test, do you have any idea how to get the log from the client ?

Comment: You could implement an error listener that collects the errors and sends them to you or writes them to a file that your client could pull off and send to you- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42948036/how-to-catch-all-errors-for-exoplayer

Comment: @Ge3ng ok thanks I will try and get back to you

Comment: You need to create an on-site [mre]